# Describe the long-term behavior of $\frac{dy}{dx}=-3y+b(t)+7$ if $b(t)$ decreases to $0$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Describe the long-term behavior (as $t\rightarrow\infty$) of

$\frac{dy}{dx}=-3y+b(t)+7$

if $b(t)$ decreases to $0$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$.

My attempt: I can see that for $y$ to be in equilibrium, i.e. $\frac{dy}{dt}=0$, we must have $y = \frac{1}{3}(b(t)+7)$, which approaches $\frac{7}{3}$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$. Are we guaranteed that $y$ will tend to this solution?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll verify that the solution of the differential equation
$$E \equiv \frac{dy}{dx}=-3y+b(t)+7$$ taking the value $y_0$ at $0$ is
$$y(t) = \left(y_0 + \int_0^t [b(u)+7]e^{3u} \ du \right) e^{-3t}$$ and 
$$\begin{aligned}
y(t) - 7/3 & = \left(y_0 + \int_0^t [b(u)+7]e^{3u} \ du \right) e^{-3t} - 7/3\\
&=\left(y_0 + 7/3 \right)e^{-3t} + \left(\int_0^t b(u)e^{3u} \ du \right) e^{-3t} 
\end{aligned}$$

Now you should be able to prove that the RHS of the equality above converges to $0$ as $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} b(t) = 0$. For that notice that if $\vert b(t) \vert < \epsilon$ for $t >T$ you have

$$\left\vert \left(\int_t^T b(u)e^{3u} \ du \right) e^{-3t}  \right\vert \le \epsilon \left(\int_0^t e^{3u} \ du \right) e^{-3t} \le \frac{\epsilon}{3} $$

Hence $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} = 7/3$.

Comment: @Jess I added some details